# How many stars are printed?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i = i+1)
    for(int j = i; j > 0; j = j/2)
        StdOut.print("*");
```

The following are the possible answers:
A) O(log N),
B) O(N),
C) O(N log N),
D) O(N^2)

I know that the answer is C), but we are confused of why that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `A`, `B`, `C` nor `D` can be an answer to the question "How many stars are printed?" because none of them are actually numbers. However, if your *actual* question is "What's the stars-printed complexity of this code?", you need to just examine the two loops :-)

The outer loop runs `N` times so that's the easier bit. It's `N`.

The inner loop starts `j` at `i` (which averages out over all the outer loops to be about `N / 2`), and halves it for each iteration. So, if `i` was `1024`, that would be about ten iterations. If `512`, about nine, `256` about eight, and so on.

That's clearly a logarithm situation where the inner loop runs a number of times that is related to `log2N`.

And, since you're running one loop within the other, you *multiply* the individual complexities to get `O(N log N)` (we don't really use the logarithm base in complexity analysis).

Comment: nicely explained

Comment: Saying "the number of stars printed is O(f(n))" seems comparable to saying "the running time is O(g(n))", which, in turn, seems comparable to "f(n) is O(g(n))". Are you actually supposed to say "the time complexity is O(g(n))"? Maybe, but the former is commonly used and there shouldn't be any ambiguity either way.

Comment: @Dukeling, you should note the smiley at the end of that first paragraph (and in this comment). Neither the question nor my answer mentioned *time* complexity, both dealt with the number of starts printed. They could of course be equated if the relationship between them was linear but that's not guaranteed :-) In any case, my answer is intended to simply *clarify* why `C` was the correct answer - I've found from painful experience that trying to explain it in formal-definition terms is counter-productive to students who aren't already *at* a rather high level of understanding.

Comment: I wasn't trying to say the number of stars printed equals the running time, but rather that both are functions, so if saying "is O(f(n))" is okay, doing so for the other should be okay too.

Comment: It's technically `log 1 + log 2 + ... + log n = log n! = O(n log n)`, not just `n` times `log n`.