# Analysis of Algorithms - Big O

Tags: algorithm, big-o

> How many stars are printed? (Choose the smallest correct estimate.)
>
> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; i = i + 1)
>     for (int j = 1; j < N / 2; j = 2 * j)
>         StdOut.print("**");
> ```
>
> 1. O(log N)
> 2. O(N)
> 3. O(N log N)
> 4. O(N^2)

I'm kind of stuck with this question and I think it is A or D but im not sure.

I know how the Big O notation work but I'm more confused about the increment in the inner loop when you multiply by 2. The reason for me to think it is A is due to the outer loop being logarithmic(?)but as I said, I'm not so sure with the inner loop. Thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you simply retype the question in the image? (BTW: You should also add why you think it could be A or D)

Comment: kindly consider adding the question in text format

Comment: [How to find time complexity of an algorithm.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Comment: I know how the Big O notation work but I'm confused about the increment in the inner loop when you multiply by 2. The reason for me to think it is A is due to the outer loop being logarithmic, but as I said, I'm not so sure with the inner loop 
Thank you in advance

Comment: @Kusra123 your last comment should be in your question instead of being a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many stars are printed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51907299/how-many-stars-are-printed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation

The outer loop generates `N / 2` iterations. For each of this iteration, the inner loop goes up to `N / 2`, but in steps of `2 * j`. That is, you reach `N / 2` in `log_2(N / 2)` steps.

---

### Example

Take the number `64`. We start at `1` and multiply by `2` in each iteration:

```
 1
 2
 4
 8
16
32
64
```

We reached `64` in `6` steps. And, indeed, `64` is `2^6`. So `log_2(64)` is `6`.

---

### Solution

So in total, you have `N / 2` iterations from the outer loop, each generating `log_2(N / 2)` iterations of the inner loop. That makes

```
N / 2 * log_2(N / 2)
```

executions of the *print line* in total. Thus, `3. O(N log N)` is the correct answer.

And, since it's *big-O*, the algorithm also runs in `4. O(N^2)`. However, `3. O(N log N)` is the smallest correct estimate.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. In summary, could you say that the outer loop is a linear O(N) and the inner loop is logarithmic O(logN) which multiplied makes it linearithmic ?

Comment: It's hard to view it that way, if you ask me. Maybe in this example, because the loops have no direct dependency of each other. All in all, you count the amount of times the `print` line is executed. The print line is inside the inner loop. The inner loop is inside the outer loop.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm more confused about the increment in the inner loop when you multiply by 2 ...

When you start with 1 and keep multiplying a variable by `2`, it'll take you `log(N) (base 2)` steps to reach `N`. Thus, the complexity of the inner loop is `O(log(N/2)` which is equivalent to `O(log(N) - log 2) = O(log(N))`.

> The reason for me to think it is A is due to the outer loop being logarithmic ...

The outer loop on the other hand is `O(N/2) = O(N)` as `i` is increasing by `1` at every step and it'll take `N/2` until `i` equals `N/2`.

Since, inner loop has no dependency on outer loop, we can multiply the complexities in this case and say that the overall complexity will be `O(N*log(N))`.

Thus, correct option is `c`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That made it more clear for me to understand now

Comment: @Kusra123 You're welcome.

Comment: I can't upvote because I need 15 reputation points and I'm going to accept the answer now!

Comment: By the way, you write `O(N/2) ~ O(N)`, but actually both sets are **equal**. `O(N/2) = O(N)` is **true**. Same for the other set in the first section.

Comment: @Zabuza Yes, If we strictly talk about `O` notation then both of these are equal.